# Connect PC with terminal commands

Tags: xubuntu, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-core

I need to connect my PC to another LAN connected PC and copy some files. How do I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, `openssh` would need to be installed on both systems. You will need `sudo` privileges to install.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Second, obtain the current IP addresses of both machines.

```
ifconfig -a
```

Third, from Machine A, where the files you want to copy are located:

```
scp /mypathtofiles/filename username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/mypathtoplacefiles
```

Substitute, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with the target system's IP address.

Note: `scp -r` may be used to recursively copy directories. It is recommended to review the `man scp` for additional information.